# Tricky convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would appreciate any help on the following problem:

> Let p > 2 and let $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers and let $a > 0$ be a real number. Assume further that $$a_k - a^2 = o\Big(\frac{3^{k(1/p-1/2)}}{\sqrt{\log(k)}}\Big)$$ then already $$3^k (a_k^{1/2} -a)^2 = o\Big(\frac{3^{2k/p}}{\log(k)}\Big).$$

I use the "small o" notation: $$a_n = o(b_n) \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\vert a_n \vert}{\vert b_n \vert}=0$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean let $p>2$ (so that $1/p-1/2<0$)?

Comment: yes, was a mistake, started with q and somehow turned to p in the process of writing

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution myself (Hopefully I'm not missing something here):

We can easily conclude that $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k = a^2$. Further $a_k, a > 0$ and hence $a_k - a^2 = (a_k^{1/2} -a)(a_k^{1/2} +a)$ implies that also $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k^{1/2} = a$.

We then obtain $$\limsup_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k - a^2}{a_k^{1/2}-a} = \limsup_{k \to \infty} a_k^{1/2}+a = 2a < \infty$$

Employing the "big O" (a definition is provided below) notation we could also write $a_k^{1/2} - a = O(a_k-a^2)$ and consequently $(a_k^{1/2} - a)^2 = O((a_k-a^2)^2)$.

Then we obtain $$3^k (a_k^{1/2} - a)^2 = O(3^k(a_k-a^2)^2)$$
and consequently $$3^k (a_k^{1/2} - a)^2 = o\Big(3^k \Big(\frac{3^{k(1/p-1/2)}}{\sqrt{\log(k)}}\Big)^2\Big)$$

Finally $$3^k \Big(\frac{3^{k(1/p-1/2)}}{\sqrt{\log(k)}}\Big)^2 = \frac{3^{2k/p}}{\log(k)},$$

which should complete the proof.

The "big O" symbole here means $$f = O(g) \Leftrightarrow \limsup_{x \to \infty} \frac{\vert f(x) \vert}{\vert g(x) \vert}<\infty$$

and we also applied the fact, that $f = O(g)$ and $g = o(h)$, then $f = o(h)$.